# .htaccess rewrite wildcard subsubdomain and params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm trying to write a mod_rewrite to work like this

- `wildcard.subdomain.domain.com` => `subdomain.domain.com/data.php?q=wildcard`
- `wildcard.subdomain.domain.com/?repeat=1` => `subdomain.domain.com/data.php?q=wildcard&repeat=1`
- `subdomain.domain.com` => `data.php`
- `www.subdomain.domain.com` => `data.php`

What I've done so far in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.abc\.def\.com\.br$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %1 !^(www)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ data.php?q=%1 
</IfModule>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
  # This should cover the first 2 cases
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.abc\.def\.com\.br$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %1 !^(www)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^$ /data.php?q=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

  # This should cover the last 2
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.abc\.def\.com\.br$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %1 ^(www)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^$ /data.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Note that this does nothing in the cases where the request is: `wildcard.subdomain.domain.com/some/path/to/file.html` These only match request URI's that are `/`.

Answer (score 1):

For repeat parameter use

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ data.php?q=%1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a cpanel , you can create a * sub domain (*.domain.com) and connect it to a directory , then create a index.php in that directory :

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

test the result , you can export sub domain names from server name or server host