# Suddomain Rewritng using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to give each dealer a unique domain name on my site, `www.goldstarrecovery.com`. I have a php page `dealer-site.php` in the root folder, which accepts username as parameter, so my goal is that when someone opens `atiq.goldstarrecovery.com` it should call the page `www.goldstarrecovery.com/dealer-site.php?username=atiq` in the background (the URL should not be changed).

Should I have to create the subdomain through my CP??

There's also an exception - this rule should not be applied to `dealer.goldstarrecovery.com`.

Comment: This is a very broad question, with a lot of parts you will need to work out.  You should create a wildcard DNS entry `*.goldstarrecovery.com` first, which will catch any not otherwise defined domain.  You then need .htaccess mod-rewrite rules to match on subdomains _other than_ `www.,dealer.` and rewrite them into the PHP script.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I can create subdomain through CP and it will create a folder of that name but how can write htaccess? Can you please guide me. I don't know how to solve my issue?

Comment: Here are two questions where a wildcard subdomain is captured by mod-rewrite as `%1` and passed to a PHP handler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568569/htaccess-rewrite-wildcard-subsubdomain-and-params and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659259/htaccess-subdomain-url-rewrite  If you create the wildcard DNS entry with your domain name registrar, you would _not_ create actual subdomains in your control panel, and instead rely only on .htaccess to route between domains. This is a very complex topic that will require a strong understanding of DNS.

Comment: What about if I want to acheive just  when someone opens atiq.goldstarrecovery.com it should call the page www.goldstarrecovery.com/dealer-site.php?username=atiq in the background (the URL should not be changed).